# SQL query tuning (subquery)

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have the below query which i want to tune as the query takes more time to run. Please help me out.

```
select  info_id 
from info_table 
where info_id not in (select info_id 
                      from some_table 
                      where info_id is not null) 
AND  rownum <= 1000 ;
```

The innerquery is returning millions of rows and hence the problem.

Comment: I would like to look at your explain plan. Don't forget to gather the tables' statistics before.

Answer (score 1):

```
select info_id
from info_table e
where not exists (select 'x' from some_table where info_id = e.info_id);
```

This will avoid the internal sort or merge and should be faster

You can even try outer join

```
select info_id
from info_table e LEFT OUTER JOIN some_table d
ON e.info_id= d.info_id
WHERE d.dept_no is not null;
```

Comment: According to my experiments your queries have the same explain plan as the author of the question does.

Comment: Ok, see [now](http://pastebin.com/Bw6Q0Ykv) (I rewrite you left join query) As I said, there is not any difference. Oracle Optimizer rewrites this query so they are the same for it. We have to add indexes or change the structure of the tables to get performance improvements.

Comment: Yes, I did, for me they last the same time. Of course we can take a look at AWR snapshots and compare numbers of latches and other locks but I don't think it matters now.

Comment: Hi Realsprituals, I tried with not exists and is functionally have conflict in the no of rows returned. Pls help me

Comment: @realspirituals You might have had some indexes on your tables, I don't have any, so it always performs full table scan.

Comment: @realspirituals Even I didnt put row count but both the query has rowcount mismatch. Peformace is indeed increased. Cost has come down from 2007 to 1017. Exec time came down from 20 secs to 8 secs

Comment: Can you post the actual query and results? Or you can give the sample datasetup with expected results in sqlfiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT info_id
  FROM info_table
  LEFT OUTER JOIN some_table ON info_table.info_id = some_table.info_id
 WHERE some_table.info_id IS NULL
```